# Can't show the video on python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I am currently trying to show a video on Python OpenCV. However, although no errors return with the code below, I still don't see the selected video played.

Environments are: Anaconda3(Python 2.7.13), Windows 7, OpenCV 3.2.0

What I tried is:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Traffic.mpg')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Appreciate for your advices.

Comment: Hi, I just encode the video accordingly into avi, however, still the same symptom can be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `opencv_ffmpeg.dll` or `opencv_ffmpeg_64.dll` in your `C\Python`. You need to have these `dlls` in order to play videos. Check this [link](https://li8bot.wordpress.com/2014/07/09/opencvpython-part-1-working-with-videos/) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

An example code snippet which answers the question may look like:

```
import cv2

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:

    ret, frame = capture.read()
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
video_capture.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What is your question?